# Code Completion for D3.js (Aptana Studio 3 or any other free IDE)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, aptana, aptana3

Is it possible to get code completion for D3.js?

It would be nice if it is possible with Aptana. If not, I could also try another IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try JetBrains' Webstorm, It support D3 and SVG , 
     So here it is [Download Webstorm here](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/)

Answer (score 1):

It's not an IDE but if you're willing to look into text editors [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) has a number of d3 plugins such as [d3.js-Sublime-2-Snippets](https://github.com/roundrobin/d3.js-Sublime-2-Snippets) and [sublime-text-d3](https://github.com/shancarter/sublime-text-d3) which should suit your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

In Aptana --> preferences/general/editors you can add file types, and change the associated editors, including using external programs.

I would venture to guess that if you find a nice IDE with autocomplete for D3.js, and enable it as an editor in Aptana, it will work nicely

Comment: hm,that doesn't help me in concrete :(

Comment: Figured halfway there is better than not at all :)